# How to display function parameters in Rider next to function names inside a code completion window?

Tags: function, parameters, popup, rider

##### When dealing with new code I like to discover all the methods I can execute on an object by typing a dot.

[image]

##### I find this feature very handy when using IntelliJ but in Rider it looks like a downgrade.

[image]

Icons like cubes, branches, tables and bags hint virtually nothing and it's difficult to tell them apart.

The part that annoys me the most is that functions parameters are displayed next to the pop-up instead of inside of it.

I don't want to go through every function to find the one that takes in the parameter I'm looking for.
I played around with the settings and nothing helped.
[image]

##### Is there a way to move function parameters inside the pop-up window?